# Why do I have several application maps in usr?

Tags: postgresql

I'm back at ubuntu after a long break. Im trying setting up postgres, pgadmin, apache etc. I've been downloading several version of the aboved mentioned applications. Before downloading new version I've been removing the old ones (they where all in /etc). Well so I thought, because now I find them in usr/shr. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applications don't lie in /etc, only their configuration files are there. An application may have files in many different places of the filesystem. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard] for a description. However, in ubuntu like in most of linux distributions, the easiest and cleanest way to install/remove application is using the package management (dpkg, apt-get, aptitude...).

Comment: Ok. Good info. But still, after removing with synaptic or apt-get remove/autoremove they're still there.